# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.storm.spout.MultiScheme.deserialize([B)Ljava/lang/Iterable;

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying to do some test about storm 1.0.1 now. And I used the topology compiled with storm 0.9.5 and submit it with backward compatibility mode `client.jartransformer.class: "org.apache.storm.hack.StormShadeTransformer"`, but I got the following exception in my spout:

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.storm.spout.MultiScheme.deserialize([B)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
>         at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.generateTuples(KafkaUtils.java:209) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>         at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:131)
> ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>         at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:141) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>         at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7885$fn__7900$fn__7931.invoke(executor.clj:645)
> ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>         at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__625.invoke(util.clj:484)
> [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>         at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_71]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Best way would be to rewrite and recompile using Storm 1.0 -- not sure why compatibility mode does not work. Maybe a bug? You might want to write to user@storm.apache.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 0.9.5 storm-core, the method of MultiScheme.class is

```
public Iterable<List<Object>> deserialize(byte[] ser);
```

but in 1.0.1 storm-core, the method of MultiScheme.class is

```
public Iterable<List<Object>> deserialize(ByteBuffer ser);
```

If you look carefully, deserialize method is rewrite, parameter byte[] change into  ByteBuffer.
so，storm throws NoSuchMethodError.
you should repackage your program with storm external storm-kafka-1.0.1.jar
 :)

Comment: does this mean Storm 1.0.x is not backward compatible?